# SQLITE_RANGE: column out of range error on UPDATE query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Apologies for a potentially very simple question, I am very new to javascript and SQLite.
I am building a webpage and on the server-side I have a database that stores all the users, their hashed passwords, sessionid, etc.

The table "Writers" consists of four columns: username, password (this is hashed, using bcrypt), sessionid, and socketid.

When a new user is registered I insert into the database, using this:

```
async registerNewWriter(username, password) {
console.log("IN REG NEW WRITER", username, password);
const saltRounds = 10; // default
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  await this.database.get(
     "INSERT INTO Writers (username, password, sessionid) VALUES (?,?,?)",
     `${username}`,
     `${hash}`,
     `null`,
 );
  // return hash;
});
```

}

After this, a session is created for the user. I update the database using this:

```
async createSession(id, socketID, username) {
console.log('create session', id, socketID, username);
await this.database.get(
      "UPDATE Writers SET sessionid = ?, socketid = ? WHERE username = ?",
      `${id}`,
      `${socketID}`,
      `${username}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
    }
);
```

}

Here is where I get the error: [Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range].

I have checked many similar questions online, but have not found the solution to this issue in particular. I have also made sure to check that sessionid, socketID and username all come into createSession with the correct values, but I do not understand why the database isn't being updated correctly.

If you know what could be wrong or have any suggestions, I will be very grateful! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are quoted and scaped as need by default, may this could be your problem. Try remove those quotes like this:

```
async createSession(id, socketID, username) {
console.log('create session', id, socketID, username);
await this.database.get(
      "UPDATE Writers SET sessionid = ?, socketid = ? WHERE username = ?",
      id,
      socketID,
      username, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your reply! I tried this, but it doesn't seem to change the outcome - I still get the same error.  Do you think it could have something to do with my INSERT-query?

Comment: As you said you had checked data I assumed insert was right. Also, your ``console.log('create session', id, socketID, username);`` take place to you check the incomming data. I just could think the id is comming in wrong format. Later I'll take a look if nobody came with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an async version, you don't need (and probably can't use) a callback :

```
some_result = await this.database.get(
      "UPDATE Writers SET sessionid = ?, socketid = ? WHERE username = ?",
      `${id}`,
      `${socketID}`,
      `${username}`
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering. I agree, after further testing, that it must be a callback issue. However, your change, unfortunately, doesn't seem to solve this for me. Maybe removing the bcrypt.hash callback, if that is possible, would work?

Comment: Another comment: I tested this version further, and what seems to happen is that the registration function (the one using bcrypt with callback), produces the hash after having gone through createSession, which seems a bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After a further struggle, I seem to have solved it! I will post my solution here, in case anyone stumbles across this with the same problem.

createSession:

```
async createSession(id, socketID, username) {
console.log('create session', id, socketID, username);
await this.database.get(
      "UPDATE Writers SET sessionid = ?, socketid = ? WHERE username = ?",
       `${id}`,
       `${socketID}`,
       `${username}`,
);
// console.log("works? 222222")
```

}

register new users (the bcrypt callback was the issue):

```
async registerNewWriter(username, password) {
console.log("IN REG NEW WRITER", username, password);
const saltRounds = 10; // default
const hashedPass = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(hash)
  });
})
// console.log("hashed pass", hashedPass)
await this.database.get(
    "INSERT INTO Writers (username, password, sessionid) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    `${username}`,
    `${hashedPass}`,
    `null`
);
// console.log("hash very finished")
```

}

I now feel quite silly, since the solution is pretty simple and not at all about the queries themselves. Big thank you to bwt for making me think about callbacks! :)